# Can't call a function through setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, function, var

I'm trying to make a few functions to work one after the other with a waiting time of 1.5 seconds between them.

NOW, when i try doing so with the same Id (Inside the "NoteList(>here<)", like 1, 2, 3, or any other, it works;

```
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++)
{
    setTimeout(function () { OnClcRandom(NoteList[0]) }, i * 1000 + 1000);

}
```

BUT! when i try doing so with the var i, it doesn't work  and gets the all of the functions in the page stuck. any idea why?

```
   for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            setTimeout(function () { OnClcRandom(NoteList[i]) }, i * 1000 + 1000);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because all of the functions refer to the same *live* `i` variable, not the value of the variable at the time you called `setTimeout()`. Which means by the time the timeouts actually run your function `i` will be `36`.

Try this instead:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        (function(x){
           setTimeout(function () { OnClcRandom(NoteList[x]) }, i * 1000 + 1000);
        )(i);
    }
```

This executes an anonymous function on each iteration of the loop, with each execution getting its own `x` parameter for use in your original function.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't create local scope for block. :)

And in your second example var i equal 36 (last value).
You need create local scope inside loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {

 (function (i) {
   setTimeout(.......);
}(i))

}
```

You also may fixed 'i' value assign it to function property:

```
for (var i = 0, f; i < 36; i++){
  f = function _callback() { var i = _callback.i; .....};
  f.i = i;
  setTimeout(f, i * 1000);
}
```